# How to use Filter results tool in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, report

I have a question about filter results tool in Jmeter.
I have a loop called "loop controller not for reports", and all I want to do is not to print in reports the values of 3 HTTP that exists in it (see pic). it is useless for me, and just expand the report (10000 records).
I understand that exists plugin that called filter results tool, and I download it via the plugin manager, the problem is that I do not understand how to use it?
1. Shall it be in UI, for example to add it like you add sampler? is it via UI?
2.I run the tests via command line, and get CSV how can I make sure not to display this steps inside the loop? (is it create another CSV? or adjust the existing one?)
3. what is the operation need to perform to use it, step by step explanation will be helpful since on net not found exactly how to use it.
Provided a PIC of the loop with the 3 http requests that I do not want to see in CSV report while I am running via command line.
can someone please clarify how to use this plugin after install it (PIC will be helpful) 
test name: loop Junk Jmeter
step name: Loop controller not for reports (include 3 HTTP inside it)
what is the command that I need to write?

regards

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) plugin example,

This is an offline process (not UI) that is execute **after** test is done and jtl results file is create

Than you need to execute command on jtl file as:

```
jmeter\lib\ext\FilterResults.bat --output-file filteredout.csv --input-file inputfile.jtl 
--exclude-labels HTTP1
```

It will create results in filteredout.csv without HTTP1 request

For excluding HTTP1,HTTP2 and HTTP3:

```
jmeter\lib\ext\FilterResults.bat --output-file filteredout.csv --input-file inputfile.jtl
 --exclude-label-regex true --exclude-labels HTTP[1-3].*
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I first run the steps via command line. and than --manually--  run this command?     Can it be together? since If I want to connect it to jenknis first I will perform the tests and afterwards this job? Is it just doing manipulation on the CSV? not connected to Jmeter?, And if I want to exclude HTTP1 + HTTP2 + HTTP3?  DO I need to run it 3 times?

Comment: I added example of HTTP1+2+3, about jenkins please ask a new question with more info how you are executing jenkins

Comment: When you mentioned --output-file filteredout.csv  , shall I put the location of the file, for example c://desktop//results.csv? can you please write if the csv from the run is located under c://desktop//results.csv and I want to create file name cleanresults.csv that will be in the same folder what is the command?

Comment: See about follow up questions in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions