# How to use Filter results Plugin tool in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Hey all this is a follow up question to 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48920778/how-to-use-filter-results-tool-in-jmeter/48920902?noredirect=1#comment84859131_48920902)
I want to remove some sampler results from CSV file.
I try to get a step by step explanation for the whole process.
The origin csv file location is c://desktop//results.csv. and I want to create another file without some sampler results.
I get this answer

```
jmeter\lib\ext\FilterResults.bat --output-file filteredout.csv --input-file inputfile.jtl
 --exclude-label-regex true --exclude-labels HTTP[1-3].*
```

Can someone please elaborate 
1. What shall I put under output-file filteredout.csv? to put location or just the name of file?

2. Is it a different process that I shall run after I get the first file?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As I see you are running on windows, so yeah, you should provide the exact path to the file. I will give you an example so you can understand how it works..
When using command line, to execute the test you do something like this:**

```
c:\>C:\apache-jmeter-3.3\apache-jmeter-3.3\bin\jmeter.bat -n -t c:\Projects\someproject.jmx -l results.jtl -Jvariable=1
```

**(-Jvariable=1) --> variable is optional(only if already set in jmx config)**

**So now you have the results.jtl file. To filter results you execute another command that looks like this:**

```
c:\>C:\apache-jmeter-3.3\apache-jmeter-3.3\bin\FilterResults.bat --output-file c:\path\to\results.jtl --input-file c:\path\to\results.jtl --exclude-labels "labels-to-be-excluded"
```

**What the last command does, it just replaces the old jtl file with the new filtered one.
To answer your questions punctually:**

**1. yes, you need to put the full path for output and input, just like you would in cmd. (you should test the command in cmd)**

**2. yes, it is a second different process that you shall run after you get the first file.**

**P.S. I've made a pipeline in jenkins that does this, and for the filter part, i've added another step like this:**

```
stage ('Cleaning stuff up') {
            // Batch build step
bat """ 
c:\>C:\apache-jmeter-3.3\apache-jmeter-3.3\bin\FilterResults.bat --output-file c:\path\to\results.jtl --input-file c:\path\to\results.jtl --exclude-labels "labels-to-be-excluded"
 """ 
    }
```

Comment: Hey isus, I am still having issues with this plug in, I uploaded the screenshots of the exception. here is what I am doing step by step   1. open cmd, writing in it this command (not navigating to anywhere just putting this command)  ---               C:\Jmeter_4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\FilterResults.bat --output-file C:\Users\Desktop\Jmeter_reports\results_geo2.csv --input-file C:\Users\Desktop\Jmeter_reports\results_geo.csv --exclude-labels "impressions to offer 33955149"
 All I am trying to do is to remove "impression to offer 33955149" from the csv, and create a new csv, can someone hel

Comment: From the screenshot, I can see that you are missing this [Merge Results](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/). You will still get the log4j2 logging error but the filter will go down without problems..lemme know if you still got issues after you install the plugin, execute the command again and verify the csv file.

Comment: It worked man, thanks a lot, I would like to know if I would like to remove 3 different labels, but using something like "Like" command in SQL. for example I would like to remove all labeles that start with impression/click/conv. is their a way to remove tham, I do not care what is after for example impression 1 or impression 2 I would like to remove all of them, and all clicks as well. regards