# time filter for jmeter aggregate report and save it again as a jtl

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

i have a jtl report of my 4 hours load test. I would like to take the results of only 2 hours and save it again as a jtl(not csv, as we can achieve in synthesis report) i Tried using sythesis report ,we get the results of particular time frame but not able to save it as jtl.

Please can anyone help me . I would like to take the results of first 2 hours and save it again as a jtl file.

Update:

I have used filterresult jar and used cmd with the mentioned command but as u can see in the screenshot after loading file result is not getting generated in the result folder.[image: Command window]

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) plugin, it has `--start-offset` and `--end-offset` parameters so you will be able to "cut" your .jtl results file for given timeframe and save it as .jtl without any transformations.

You can install Filter Results Tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager Filter Results]

Comment: may i know the compatibility of this plugin.I'm not able to find in jmeter 3.1 tree. howver i already have the plugin  kn ext folder

Comment: @shey This is not a default plugin.. You can either use plugin manager(https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) to download this or you can directly download it. (https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/)  .I have this in 3.0, so probably it will support 3.1

Comment: @sunny_teo i already have the mentioned plugin in EXT folder.But im not able to find in jmeter tree.

Comment: @Shey..My bad...I missed the point. I have checked the plugin page and it looks like it will not reflect in the tree and is a command line tool/plugin. You can check the plugin manager site for different options and how to run it. 1 more thread to look for:-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48930943/how-to-use-filter-results-plugin-tool-in-jmeter

Comment: dmitri @sunny_teo please check ,i have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

@Shey..Please check the below [plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SynthesisReport/), It has the GUI and you can filter the results. I hope this is easier than cmd line.

[image]

Comment: yes we can use that ,but we can not export as jtl right.i want result to be in jtl format .as im going to perform a task on jtl file specifically.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is not providing the jtl output. It seems like plugin is crashing as there is nothing after loading. I am not able to reproduce the same, so lets wait for @Dmitri T

Comment: @Dmitri T ,kindly can you come up with any suggestions.

Comment: @Shey..CSV is also a format of JTL. So, if you get the csv from the above plugin and change the extension of csv to jtl then you will have the jtl file for further processing. It is just a thought and since you have the actual data you can try it.